# Django cannot find TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a login page using django and I am getting this error.

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/
registration/login.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/
Django Version: 4.1.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
registration/login.html
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 47, in select_template
Raised during:  django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.11.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/jasonfan/Desktop/Swe/TAPortal',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python311.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 20 Mar 2023 17:02:00 +0000
```

I have a couple ideas of where the problem may lie. I created a templates/registration/login.html. Does it matter which directory i put these subdirectories in? My file structure is attached.

```
This is my settings.py folder. I modified TEMPLATES. I added 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/"templates"], I also added LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/" at the bottom.
```

```
    TEMPLATES = [
            {
                'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
                'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/"templates"],
                'APP_DIRS': True,
                'OPTIONS': {
                    'context_processors': [
                        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                        'django.template.context_processors.request',
                        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    ],
                },
            },
        ]
```

I also modified urls.py adding

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('accounts/', include("django.contrib.auth.urls"))
    ]
```

I modified the login.html to a basic login screen and that is where I am trying to get to when i run server. I do http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/

Comment: You have an `/accounts` path, but not `/accounts/login/`.  How will it find the right page?

Comment: in settings.py, it should be TEMPLATES = {"DIRS": [BASE_DIR + "/templates"],}

Comment: @EliuS I dont think concatenation is possible in this context it will create an error

Comment: @TimRoberts Do i do i modify my current one to /accounts/login/? it still doesnt work

Comment: @jasonfan That's the configuration I'm using. BASE_DIR should be a string Mine: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) so just appending "/templates" should work. Your line gives me an TypeError.

Comment: @TimRoberts I think the urls path is valid. It's included in the contrib.auth.urls

Comment: @jasonfan -- `settings.py` is simple Python code.  Any Python operation is valid.  The `/` operator works only if `BASE_DIR` is a `Path` object.  If it's a string, then you must use concatenation.

Comment: @jsonfan Try putting your login.html Template in the folder "templates/accounts/" or "templates/accounts/registration/". Alternatively if you use the LoginView directly in your urls.py file you can use the path to the tempalte as an argument: LoginView.as_view(template_name="registration/login.html").